# what version of visual studio is needed for sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, sharepoint-server, development, visual-studio

what version of visual studio is needed for sharepoint 2010 besides VS2010? My question is whether or not a sharepoint 2010 server can support newer versions of VS?

Comment: Hello @Vusi45 , Your feedback is very important 1. Are the below answers didn't helped you? 2. do you need any further clarifications? if yes, please comment to the provided answers with your clarifications to can help you or edit your question with these clarifications, else please upvote and mark the correct answer that helped you as accepted to close this question. Also, please check [Tour](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour) to know how can you accept the correct answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**The below are the supported/unsupported `Visual Studio` versions for `SharePoint 2010`**

- **Visual Studio 2017**: **No**.

  > Visual Studio 2017 is supported for SharePoint 2016, SharePoint 2013 and Office 365 for more details, check [Install Office / SharePoint Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2017](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/03/11/missing-sharepoint-template-in-vs2017/)
- **Visual Studio 2015**: **Yes**.

  > For more details check [Missing SharePoint 2016 Project Template in Visual Studio 2015.](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/07/14/office-sharepoint-template-missing-in-visual-studio-2015/)
- **Visual Studio 2013**: **Yes**.

  > For more details check [Couldn’t find office/SharePoint template in Visual Studio Community 2013.](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/01/15/missing-officesharepoint-template-in-visual-studio-community-2013/)

Answer (score -2):

Refer to the flloiwng article about Availability of Features in Visual Studio Versions:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee519072.aspx